# visual studio configuration directory changes automatically

Tags: visual-studio, directory, properties, macros, directory-structure

hi i have been using visual studio for like 10 years.
and recently found out that the directory i set in header&lib directory in property configuration.

something like

`$(SolutionDir)\x64\Release;`

into

`C:\Users\Name\source\repos\Framework\x64\Release;`

it is just hard coded.

i want to keep in macro like `SolutionDir` because i want to make this project public so that the directory is still valid for people who download my project.

couldn't really find out how to fix this macro.

Guess i am just missing something simple.

Comment: It is not clear from the question *where* it changes, or whether it's a display problem vs. a saved property problem. Open the project file in a text (or xml) editor, does it contain the macro or the expansion?

Comment: i couldn't really find that timing. just guessing it changes when vs is closed and reopen, or rebuilding projects, not really sure. and Yes in project file, it is changed to just full path, not a macro. so i came to just make define branch in code.